# How to overwrite browserify bundle file (?)

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, bundle, browserify

Ok, for starters I don't even know if that question makes sense, so let me explain.

I've been working with Node.js module browserify recently and came across somehting rather odd.

I was able to successfuly add bundle files to my public resources folder using 'browserify main.js -o public/bundle.js', but the deal is when I try to change these files.

Once I used the command above, a bundle.js file was automatically created in the designated folder, but I can seem to make changes in this file.

If I go and modify directly the bundle.js file, nothing seems to change when I run the program. Also, if I change my main.js file and try to browserify it to the same file (using again 'browserify main.js -o public/bundle.js'), nothing seems to change (even if I delete the bundle.js file first).
It seems like the only way to successfuly apply the changes is to create a new bundle file ('browserify main.js -o public/bundle2.js').

Does anyone a way to apply the changes always to the same file, so I don't have to create a new one everytime I make a change in my function?

Note: When I open Google Chrome Developer Tools Console and inspect the element that calls the functions, even after deleting the file and creating a new one, I get the code from the old file.

Thanks in advance!

Bye!

Comment: Is this specific to browserify at all? Do you get this behavior for other javascript files? This sounds like an issue with your webserver or HTTP caching.

Comment: Didnt really found an answer for this, guess must be indeed something related to clearing the cache, but doing this doenst work all the times